# How to set li class active in laravel?

Tags: laravel

My current url is `http://localhost:8000/category/1`

**I am trying to set active class of li as per url id.**

1st Try:

```
@foreach($category as $categories)
      <a href="{{ route('category.index',$categories->id)}}" class="list-group-item {{ Request::is($categories->id) ? 'active' : '' }}">{{$categories->name}}</a>
@endforeach
```

**Output: No li gets active class**

2nd Try:

```
@foreach($category as $categories)
  <a href="{{ route('category.index',$categories->id)}}" class="list-group-item @if (Request::url('/category/{{$categories->id}}')) {{'active'}} @endif">{{$categories->name}}</a>
@endforeach
```

**Output: all li gets active class**

**Suppose url is http://localhost:8000/category/2 then I want the second li to get highlighted.**

Thanks.

Comment: Not related, but are you sure about `@foreach($category as $categories)`? Usually it's `@foreach($categories as $category)`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin in my controller i passed it as category instead of categories that is my I wrote it other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{{ request()->segment(2) == $categories->id ? 'active' : '' }}
```

Comment: can you tell me why did you pass 2 in segment.

Comment: @Phoenix because it's the second segment of URI. For example, `segment(1)` will return `category`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel's `request()->segments()` method to get the segments (in the form of array) from the url like this:

```
@php
    $segments = request()->segments();
@endphp

@foreach($category as $categories)
  <a href="{{ route('category.index',$categories->id)}}" class="list-group-item {{ (last($segments) == $category->id) ? 'active' : ''  }}>{{$categories->name}}</a>
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps!